# How to determine what is scheduling a job to run or starting it in linux/debian?

Tags: linux, debian, cron, rsync, task-scheduler

I've searched and found similar questions asked, but either they don't answer it or I'm not understanding.

We have a linux file server that is scheduled to make backups using rsync. I noticed that our backup drive is using more storage space than it should be so I need to modify my backup strategy. I could swear the job was managed by cron, however I am not finding any cronjobs schedule at all besides some calls to anacron which I'm assuming were scheduled by the system as I never set those up. This is leaving me very confused and I'm not sure how the job is being run.

Following this I issued a "ps aux | grep rsync" to check if it is running and I have multiple issues for rsync which confuses me even further. Rsync should not actually be running at all right now since it's the middle of the day, that's pointing towards another issue I need to address, but for now I just need to figure out where it's even being called from. Below are the entries of the ps aux call. Is there any way to somehow determine what is calling rsync to begin with? I'm not asking where the executable lies or under what user it's being executed but by what process it is that is executing it.

```
root@nmpmain:/etc/cron.daily# ps aux | grep rsync
root     17318  0.0  0.0   4336   580 ?        Ss   10:00   0:00 /bin/sh -c rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     17319  2.2  0.0  51156  7244 ?        S    10:00   3:35 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     17320  0.0  0.0  42608  3912 ?        S    10:00   0:01 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     17321  8.5  0.0  54936  5968 ?        R    10:00  13:55 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18028  0.0  0.0   4336   748 ?        Ss   11:00   0:00 /bin/sh -c rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18029  1.2  0.0  51156  7756 ?        S    11:00   1:18 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18030  0.0  0.0  42608  4092 ?        S    11:00   0:01 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18031  8.2  0.0  54936  5984 ?        D    11:00   8:29 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18753  0.0  0.0   4336   752 ?        Ss   12:00   0:00 /bin/sh -c rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18754  0.7  0.1  52692  8288 ?        S    12:00   0:18 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18755  0.0  0.0  42608  4400 ?        S    12:00   0:01 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     18756  6.9  0.0  54936  6332 ?        R    12:00   2:59 rsync -rvulpEAXogt /nmp /backup
root     19754  0.0  0.0  12728  2116 pts/0    S+   12:42   0:00 grep rsync
```

Comment: If you haven't found it in the /etc/cron* directories, do you have it in 'crontab -e' of root or some of users?

Comment: I checked all crontabs, /etc/cron files and all users on the system. I'm currently just searching all files on the system to see if they contain the string "rsync -rvulpEAXogt". It's going to take awhile to run, but if I don't find a better way that should hopefully give me an answer eventually haha.

Answer (score 0):

First, carefully examine the logs you can find in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/cron`.

If you can't find anything in the logs, execute a `ps axf` to see the running process calling tree.